# Why Rails is creating many test schemas when I am running the tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

When I am running some tests on my Model, Rails is creating **four more test schemas on MySQL**.  So, after I run: `$ bin/rails test`, I have these four schemas generated by Rails.

[image]

I also have `blog_development`, which it's ok..

I did the migrations, filled the fixtures and coded an example test. I have an example app here: https://github.com/rgiaviti/poc-so-rails-creating-many-test-schemas

Below, are some of my codes:

### Migrations

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.text :body, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :articles
  end
end

class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.references :article, null: false
      t.text :body, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_foreign_key :comments, :articles
  end

  def down
    remove_foreign_key :comments, :articles
    drop_table :comments
  end
end
```

### Fixtures

```
article-1:
  title: This is the Article 1
  body: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in erat tortor. Proin et dolor vitae erat blandit molestie. Ut vehicula finibus felis, tempor accumsan justo faucibus vitae

article-2:
  title: This the Article 2
  body: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in erat tortor. Proin et dolor vitae erat blandit molestie.


comment-1:
  article: article-1
  body: A Comment

comment-2:
  article: article-1
  body: "Some Comment"

comment-3:
  article: article-2
  body: Comment for other article
```

### Test

```
require "test_helper"

class ArticleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should not save article without title" do
    article = Article.new
    article.body = "Body for an Article"
    assert_not article.save
  end
end
```

### My Environment

- MySQL: 8.0.24 (Running with Docker)
- Rails: Rails 6.1.3.1
- RVM Version: rvm 1.29.12;
- Ruby Version: ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your [`test/test_helper.rb`](https://github.com/rgiaviti/poc-so-rails-creating-many-test-schemas/blob/main/test/test_helper.rb#L7) you have the following directive, which I believe is part of the initial default test suite creation:

```rb
parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)
```

This is a feature that was introduced into core Rails with version 6, creating independent test schemas so that multiple tests can run in parallel without interfering with each others' database access.

For more on this, see the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TestCase.html#method-c-parallelize) and a write-up of the feature on [BigBinary](https://bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-adds-parallel-testing). From the docs:

> For each process a new database will be created suffixed with the worker number.
>
> ```
> test-database-0
> test-database-1
> ```

Comment: That's it! Thanks. One last question. Do you know why Rails doesn't drop those databases (`blog_test-0, blog_test-1...`) when I run `rake db:drop` or `rake db:reset`? The databases `blog_development` and `blog_test` are dropped.